# How to adjust Capybara finders on a site using css-modules?

Tags: css, selenium, rspec, capybara, css-modules

In our automated tests, a typical line in our code might look something like:

`find('.edit-icon').click`

We're on our way to using css-modules in our project and I've been warned that class names may change dramatically.  A pretty zany example is this site that uses emojis in its class names (when you inspect the page):

[css modules by Glenn Maddern](http://glenmaddern.com/articles/css-modules)

How might I best prepare for a change this drastic?  I imagine many of our specs breaking, but I am a little worried about being unable to write tests at all with this new technology in our project.

Comment: One way is to use custom Capybara selectors - https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/selector.rb - to abstract things so you can do something like `find(:edit_button).click`.  The full answer though is "it depends" - why did you use the css class in the first place?

Comment: In the example I provided, which is common throughout my project, I end up with buttons and other elements that can not be found through any identifying text or other attributes.  I also tend to use class name selectors to avoid any ambiguity/false positives in writing expectations (for example, if some text is expected to jump from one area to another).  I hope that as our project goes along, I can provide some more specific examples.  Are classes not typically used in automated specs?  Thank you for the help, Tom.

Comment: yes classes are used quite a lot -- although I tend to try and use them as last resort.  Elements where there is no text, other attributes, etc  are the primary use case.   As I mentioned custom selectors can help here - Capybara.add_selector(:edit_button) { css do | locator|  '.edit-icon' end }  - which would then isolate the css to one place.  When the class names change you can change that selector and maybe do something like '[class*="\_edit\_"]' when you go to css modules, depending on how the class names end up getting composed

Comment: and of course since it's just CSS selectors you can work through a transition period by allowing for both forms so something like `Capybara.add_selector(:edit) { css do | locator| '.edit-icon, *[class*="_edit_"]' end }` would allow   find(:edit).click  to click both  -- This all supposes you have more than one place where you're currently doing find('.edit-icon').click of course.

Comment: This might be more appropriate in a PM or separate thread, but I think what might help me the most might be to extend the find method in Capybara::Node::Finders to consider regex in class and ID names. I'm not very adept with OO programming and extending classes, would you be able to point me in the right direction? I can see this perhaps being useful in the Capybara project if css-modules take off in the js community (and maybe one day I'd be ambitious enough to put up a PR to support this).

Comment: The problem you're going to have with that is most browsers only support XPath 1.0 which doesn't have any regex support (CSS has no regex support) - and trying to do it outside the browser (as a filter in a selector) may make things really slow.  Anyway there is no need to extend find, just create your own custom selector that does whatever you prefer and then set Capybara.default_selector to that selector  -- You can do whatever CSS or XPath query you want with the value passed in (hopefully you get by with only substring matching ( *= attribute selector or contains() XPath).

Comment: Hey Tom, one last thing.  I'm not sure if custom selectors will help in my situation.  I believe I will have to refactor ALL of my specs to go from something like `find('.whatever').click` to `find('[class^=".whatever"]').click`.  Is there a way to break this out into a custom selector?

Comment: yep - something like `Capybara.add_selector(:class_starts_with) do css {|locator| "[class^=\"#{locator}\"]" } end` which you can then call  find(:class_starts_with, ".whatever")  or set Capybara.default_selector = :class_starts_with  - not sure if you actually want the '.' in the final selector but you can manipulate locator however you want just return the required css selector from the block passed to `css` (you can use an XPath expression instead by passing a block to `xpath` rather than `css`)

Comment: That is perfect!!  Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome - I've moved it through to an answer so you can mark the question as answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using custom capybara selectors you can abstract away from the actual css query being done and move it to one location.  In your comments you mentioned the need to change to a class attribute that begins with a passed in value.

```
Capybara.add_selector(:class_starts_with) do
  css { |locator| "[class^=\"#{locator}\"]"
end
```

would do that and then can be called as

```
find(:class_starts_with, 'something')
```

or if you set Capybara.default_selector = :class_starts_with it would just be

```
find('something')
```

Rather than changing default_selector another option would be to just define a helper method like find_by_class_start or something that just calls find with :class_starts_with passed (how Capybara's #find_field, etc work).

Also note the custom selector above would only really work if only one class name was set, if multiple are expected you could change the selector to `"[class^=\"#{locator}\"], [class*=\" #{locator}\"]"`

Comment: Hey Tom, is there also a way for me to add a custom matcher for `have_css` like we did for `find()`?  I can't seem to find any documentation on that either.

Comment: @Phil `have_css(...)` is basically just `have_selector(:css, ...)`and `have_selector(...)` defaults to Capybara.default_selector if no other selector passed.  So you could do `have_selector(:class_starts_with,...)`

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that! Thank you for all the help through this whole thread.  I really, really appreciate it.