# CSS Modules with Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, integration-testing, css-modules, react-css-modules

I'm working on a web app using React/Redux and CSS Modules. For unit tests I'm using [identity-obj-proxy](https://github.com/keyanzhang/identity-obj-proxy) to mock my CSS imports.

However, the QA team is wondering how to proceed with the obfuscated class names when using Selenium (which I'm completely unfamiliar with myself). The only mention of the two together that I've been able to find [is this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38622288/how-to-adjust-capybara-finders-on-a-site-using-css-modules), but the accepted answer wasn't clear to QA.

What are some of the solutions for using Selenium in this situation (preferably an easy-to-understand answer that I can go to the QA team with)?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to handle this, [as documented here](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/issues/194).

I ended up turning off CSS hashing in the webpack config for our dev environment (via the `localIdentName` option provided by [CSS Loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader)).

For example, `localIdentName=[name]__[local]` rather than the default `localIdentName=[hash:base64]`.

Answer (score 1):

I created webpack plugin [webpack-cssmap-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-cssmap-plugin). It allows to create the JSON file with mapping between original class and obfuscated class names. So it is possible to not add long classnames with **localIdentName** to your HTML

Answer (score 0):

I think using the CSS selector in BDD test is better, because we can keep the same webpack config as production. And use CSS selector is very easy compared using the Xpath.

Here's an example:

```
const {By} = require('selenium-webdriver');

// Use `contains` wild card to match, and put it in function to reuse.
const hashedClassName = (className) => By.css('[class*=\'' + className + '\']');

// skip other setting .....

describe('Foo Page', function() {
  it('There should be a bar component', function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      browser
        .get(serverUri + 'foo')
        .catch(err => reject(err));

      // I assume the webpack will use something like below:
      // localIdentName: '[name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]'
      browser
        .findElement(hashedClassName('Foo__bar'))
        .then(elem => resolve())
        .catch(err => reject(err));
    });
  });
});
```

P.S. The demo is using nodejs, I assume Python has the similar features.