# How can I prevent className from being hashed in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Our team uses Google Tag Manager and Optimizely in our Nextjs application. Both of these tools use CSS selectors to target sections of the page. We are using [CSS Modules](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-component-level-css)

Every time we deploy code, our class name are hashed and will break the selectors because the classname has been changed.

```
<div class="Button_test__1iM5u">
```

How can I add a classname along side of the hash classname? Or something that allows me to have a class that does not get hashed every deployment.

```
<div class="ButtonTest Button_test__1iM5u">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:** `` <div className={`constant-class ${styles.cssModuleClass}`} /> `` or use aria or data attributes to query.

I figured this would be a common problem as things like `e2e/webdriver` tests would have a hard time with it too.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46290806/16189248) is a similar question, and it seems you can configure either `webpack` to handle the styles or add a 'constant' `className` prefix (which you can still query with CSS selectors), which points to this [discussion](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/issues/194#issuecomment-262625515).