# css module preserve original class name nextJS

Tags: webpack, next.js, css-modules

the output of next generates a classname_hash,
how can it be configured (via webpack) so that in "addition" to the classname_hash it also preserves the original class name?

I still want to use CSS modules to benefit of all its goodness, but for other reasons keep the original class name too.

```
import styles from '../styles.module.css'
...
    <div className={styles.hello}>Hello World</div>
...
```

Without any change it omits:

```
    <div class="hello__Ux3Zx">Hello World</div>
```

Is there a way to configure webpack to have them both like this?

```
    <div class="hello__Ux3Zx hello">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: use global styles instead of module/page based styles.

Comment: I still want to benefit from css modules

Comment: can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70008994/how-can-i-prevent-classname-from-being-hashed-in-nextjs @adardesign

Comment: @OMiShah Thanks but none of those 3 solutions work for me.
my question is how to configure it within nextJS to use both hash and original class  without the need to repeat myself

Comment: then you can declare the same classname, one in global css file and another in module based style file and then use as ``<div className={`${styles["hello"]} hello`}>Hello World</div>``. It should work.

Comment: regarding your last part try checking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66744765/how-to-hash-css-class-names-in-nextjs

Comment: Thanks, I am trying without the need to repeat

Comment: Then you can configure the webpack to not hash or hash but also includ unhashed classname.

Comment: @OMiShah, ok, then this question is how to do it

Comment: check the link from my last 3rd comment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how to configure this in next.config, but there is another solution. It also stores the class name but this class will be global.
So this is both an advantage and a disadvantage. If you name A component with the same class, the styles that you previously set for this class will be applied to that A component as well

```scss
.container_hello {
//some styles

  :global(.hello) {
   //some styles
  }
}

or

:global(.hello) {
 //some styles
}
```

And it will look like this in html dom

```html
 <div class="container_hello__Ux3Zx">
   <div class="hello">Hello World</div>
 </div>

 <div class="hello">Hello World</div>
```